# How to use dplyr to calculate difference between a set of rows and a target row?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am stuck with a data manipulation problem. Basically I have a data frame with two factor columns and a response variable, like the following:

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:10,each=4),
                 Condition = factor(rep(c("A","B","C","D"),10)),
                     Resp = runif(40,0,1))
```

What I would like to accomplish is to create a new column `Resp_new` which, for each ID, includes the difference of `Resp` between the level `A` of the variable `Condition` and the remaining levels `B`,`C` and `D`.

I would like to solve this problem with **dplyr**, since it is my main tool for data manipulation, but any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the dataset is ordered as in the example, this is easily accomplished in base R with `ave`.

```
df$respNew <- ave(df$Resp, df$ID, FUN=function(i) i - i[1])
```

The first argument to `ave` is the vector to manipulate, the second is the grouping variable.  The third is the function to use in the manipulation. This is simply the difference of the first element (ID == A) and all of the elements of the vector groups.

The first six rows return

```
 head(df)
  ID Condition      Resp    respNew
1  1         A 0.1137034  0.0000000
2  1         B 0.6222994  0.5085960
3  1         C 0.6092747  0.4955713
4  1         D 0.6233794  0.5096760
5  2         A 0.8609154  0.0000000
6  2         B 0.6403106 -0.2206048
```

Comment: if you still want dplyr after this excellent answer :) . df %>% mutate(respNew= ave(Resp, ID, FUN=function(i) i - i[1]))

Comment: @thisisrg Or, just throw in a token dplyr function :) `df$respNew <- df$Resp - ave(df$Resp, df$ID, FUN = dplyr::first)`